# How to duplicate form content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="fields_1">
        <input name="field1_1" type="...
        <input name="field2_1" type="...
        <input name="field3_1" type="...
        <input name="field4_1" type="...
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="duplicate();">Duplicate</a>
</form>
```

and i want to duplicate on click  all fields but different names, for example when I click "Duplicate" it shows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="fields_1">
        <input name="field1_1" type="...
        <input name="field2_1" type="...
        <input name="field3_1" type="...
        <input name="field4_1" type="...
    </div>
    <div id="fields_2">
        <input name="field1_2" type="...
        <input name="field2_2" type="...
        <input name="field3_2" type="...
        <input name="field4_2" type="...
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="duplicate();">Duplicate</a>
</form>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$('#fields_1').clone().attr("id","fields_2").appendTo('#yrContainer');
```

Where yrContainer is either the form, or maybe a new div container.  If you need to change input names shown below, and here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TyD7X/2/).

```
$("#myButton").click( function () {
    var fields = $('#fields_1').clone().attr("id","fields_2"); 
    var inputs = fields.find("input");
    inputs.each(function(i) {
     $(this).attr("name", "field"+i+"_2");
   });   
  fields.appendTo('#yrContainer')
})
```

Comment: Yes, but this not change names and div id

Comment: I have included the code to change id. To change fields names, I would then do a separate piece of code to change each inputs name.

Comment: Won't this make it a child of #fields_1?

Comment: Thanks, but what about input in new div names?

Answer (score 1):

First: Add class="items" to the  container

```
<div id="fields_1" class="items">
 ...
</div>
```

Second: Move out of the form the 'Duplicate' link.

```
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="duplicate();">Duplicate</a>
```

Third: Try with this code:

```
function duplicate(){
    // Get content to clone
    var line_to_clone = $('#fields_1').html();

    // Get new line id
    var next_line_id = $('.items').length + 1;

    // Add the div container
    var line_to_clone = '<div id="fields_' + next_line_id + '" class="items">' + line_to_clone + '</div>';

    // Create new line
    var new_line = line_to_clone.replace(/_1/gi, "_" + next_line_id);

    // Render it
    $('form').append(new_line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `duplicate()` function. That would be the pure javascript way the way you have written it. For Jquery you need to have a clone method, rather than writing anything called duplicate(). Should be very brief and crisp.